# Best approach for a PDE containing an integral?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following PDE:
$$A_z=A_x+\int A dt\cdot A$$
with $A$ a complex function. How can I separate the variables, such that the equation can be solved? Simple integration would lead to a double integral on the right hand side. Or should I rather differentiate on both sides?
In the original form it is
$$A_z=A_x+f\cdot A$$
with 
$$\frac{df}{dt}=c\cdot \vert A\vert^4$$
and $c$ as a constant. Thus I thought that I can rewrite it as following:
$$\begin{split}
\frac{df}{dt}&=c\cdot A\\
df&=c\cdot A\cdot dt\\
\int df &= c\cdot \int A(t)dt\\
f&=c\cdot\int A(t)dt\end{split}$$
Is that correct?

Comment: So $A = A(x,z,t)$? And does $$\int A dt \cdot A = A \int A dt$$?

Comment: Added explanation, I hope that helps.

Comment: You should have limits of integration for your integral, otherwise this does not really make any sense.

Comment: I think you are missing some things. For example, what is $f$ a function of? If $f = f(t)$, then the solution is just $A = g(z+x) \exp(-x f(t))$ for arbitrary $g$, but I don't think $f$ is just a function of $t$.

Comment: @Mattos: I added how I got to $f(t)$, and how the derivation of $f$ is created.

Answer (score 1):

$$A_z=A_x+A\int A dt$$
I will not answer to the textual question : Best approach for a PDE containing an integral?

I will only answer to the question : An approach to simplify a PDE containing an integral ?

Let $\quad A(x,z,t)=e^{F(x,z,t)} \quad\to\quad A_x=A\:F_x \quad;\quad A_z=A\:F_z $

$$F_z=F_x+\int e^F dt$$
Then, differentiating with respect to $t$ :
$$F_{z,t}=F_{x,t}+e^F$$
which is a non-linear second order PDE, on a more usual form than a PDE containing an integral.

By the way, if the question was to solve the PDE, this would be a different kettle of fish.

Comment: If I extend the question to "How to solve it?", what would the answer be in that case?

Comment: As I already said :  This would be a different kettle of fish. Now, I add : I am not fisherman and the fish is too big.